# How does the elements of a nilpotent ideal look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How does the elements of a nilpotent ideal look like? In my book it is just mentioned that an ideal I is nilpotent if $I^n=0$ for some $n.$ Does it mean if for some n, the n-th power of every element of the ideal is zero only then it is nilpotent?

Answer (score 2):

Not quite.  A (left, right, or twosided) ideal is called **nil** if all of its elements are nilpotent.  If the same $n$ works for all elements, you’d say it has a bounded index of nilpotence.

Being a **nilpotent** (left, right or two sided)  ideal is even stronger. It means that for some fixed $n$, *every product of $n$ elements from the set is zero.* That is, it is nilpotent with respect to [*ideal multiplication*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)#Ideal_operations), i.e.  $I^n=\{0\}$.

For example, take a field $F$ and look at $F[x_1,x_2\ldots]$ in a countably infinite number of variables, and consider the quotient ring using the ideal generated by all the $x_i^2$.  In the quotient, the ideal generated by the $x_i$ is nil, but not nilpotent, since there are nonzero elements of the form $\prod_{i=1}^n x_i$ for arbitrarily high $n$.

Given any ring $R$ with a proper ideal $I$, the quotient $R/I^n$ has $I/I^n$ as a nilpotent ideal.

Comment: @Arthur I did a bit to magnify what you mentioned.